# Can't select object in viewport but can in outliner as edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, edit-mode, viewlayers

While working with a car model, somehow selection in viewport is disabled, but I can select objects in outliner and pressing tab can allow me to work in edit mode.[image]

Kindly see my blend file: [image]

Comment: Press the select icon in outliner of an object, then you can select in viewport.

Comment: it is the left most icon on the right side...just in case... ;)

Comment: Do you want to be unable to select in the outliner too ?